# Is there any way to remove the component selector tag without removing it's content?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular-components

**Output:**

```
<test-1>
 <ul>
    <test-1-item>
       <li>Home</li>
    </test-1-item>
    <test-1-item>
       <li>About</li>
    </test-1-item>
</ul>
</test-1>
```

**Output I want:**

```
<test-1>
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    .
    .
</ul>
</test-1>
```

**Problem:**

Getting test-1-item tag as parent of li.

**Question:**

I know that by considering it as directive and passing it to li tag will clear the issue but I want it as component. Is there any way to achieve it using the component?

Items are not passed as array, passed individually.

Sample code is given below:

```
<test-1>
    <test-1-item>Home</test-1-item>
    <test-1-item>About</test-1-item>
    <test-1-item>Contact</test-1-item>
</test-1>
```